# Error screen while loading sharedpreferences Flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, loading

Hi I'm having a problem using SharedPreferences on my Flutter app. I'm getting an error screen while loading the SharedPreferences I want to expose in my build function. At the moment everything is loaded I can use my app without error.
The error code I get : "The method getStringList was called on null". This is my code:

```
SharedPreferences sp;
List<String> toprun = ["181","103","90","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"];

@override
void initState(){

SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((SharedPreferences shared)
{
  sp = shared;
  sp?.setStringList('toprun', toprun);
});      //Setting Data in my sp 
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('Title'),
    backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
  ),
  body: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 40.0, 30.0, 0.0),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget> [
        DataTable(
          columns: [
            DataColumn(label: Text('Results')),
          ],
          rows:
          sp.getStringList('toprun') // Get data I previously saved in my sp
              .map(
            ((element) => DataRow(
              cells: <DataCell>[
                DataCell(Text(element)),
              ],
            )),
          )
              .toList()
        )
      ],
    )
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: NavBarWidget(index: 0,),
);
}
```

Comment: could you please add the error to the question?

Comment: I did. It says "The method 'getStringList' was called on null".

Comment: you might avoid using async code in initstate

Comment: to add to Kadri's comment: your `sp` is null, when you call `getStringList` on it in `build`, because your code in `SharedPreferences.getInstance().then(...)` runs asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an untested guess, but i think `sp.getStringList('toprun')` returns a promise.. so you would have to wait (await) for it or use a futureBuilder.. As i said, it's a guess, but calling  `.map` on a future might result in an error

Edit: I tested it and it's not the problem. As @kadri-nadir says, the problem is that initState isn't meant for asny stuff.. so sp is still null while the build--method is called... The following works for me:

```dart
class _MyAppState2 extends State<MyApp2> {
  List<String> toprun = ["181","103","90","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"];

  @override
  void initState(){
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((SharedPreferences shared){
      shared.setStringList('toprun', toprun);
    });      //Setting Data in my sp
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Title'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
      ),
      body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 40.0, 30.0, 0.0),
          child:
          FutureBuilder<SharedPreferences>(future: SharedPreferences.getInstance(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<SharedPreferences> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      DataTable(
                          columns: [
                            DataColumn(label: Text('Results')),
                          ],
                          rows:
                          snapshot.data.getStringList(
                              'toprun') // Get data I previously saved in my sp
                              .map(
                            ((element) =>
                                DataRow(
                                  cells: <DataCell>[
                                    DataCell(Text(element)),
                                  ],
                                )),
                          )
                              .toList()
                      )
                    ]);
              }
              return Text('No data');
            })
      ),
    );
  }
}
```